# Graph over unit vectors with adjacent vertices a fixed angle

Tags: graph-theory

Given a set of points on the plane you can construct
[unit distance graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_distance_graph)
by taking the points as vertices, and setting two points as adjacent if the distance between the two points is one.

I am curious about something analogous to this on a sphere.

Is there anything known about, for a fixed angle $\theta$ and dimension $n$, the graph whose vertices are the unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a pair of vertices adjacent if only if the angle between the two vectors are exactly $\theta$. I will refer to this as $G(n, \theta)$.

I am wondering if there are any bounds on the chromatic number of $G(n, \theta)$?  I know for example that it contains $K_{n-1}$ because, if you set $\alpha = \sqrt{\cos{\theta}}$ and $\beta = \sqrt{1-\cos{\theta}}$ the vectors

- $(\alpha, \beta, 0, 0,\ldots, 0)$
- $(\alpha, 0, \beta, 0, \ldots, 0)$
- ...
- $(\alpha, 0, 0, \ldots, \beta)$

are all adjacent.

If you set $n = N^2 + N + 1$ and $\theta = \arccos{\frac{1}{N+1}}$, then you can get $K_n$ by having the dimensions correspond to the points in a projective plane of size $n$, and having the unit vectors correspond to the $n$ lines with $N+1$ non-zero entries each $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N+1}}$ for each point in the line.

I there a way to get subgraphs in $G(n, \theta)$ with high chromatic numbers?

Comment: As in the Hadwiger-Nelson problem, you obtain a finite colouring by dividing the sphere into patches of angular diameter less than $\theta$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the angle between two vectors $u$ and $v$? Is it the same as the angle between $u$ and $-v$? If not, then for $\theta$ great than $\pi/2$ the graph is related to the Lovasz theta function. Also for $\theta > \pi/2$ your construction for finding $K_{n-1}$ does not necessarily work. For instance, if $\theta = \pi$ then only antipodal vectors are adjacent, so the graph is just a perfect matching.

Comment: I believe the graph is also somewhat related to the topological bound for chromatic number.